# Stopping underlying Sparkcontext inside Sparksession repeatedly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a code like this:

`main.py`

```py
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()
process._process(spark_session)
```

`process.py`

```py
def _process(spark_session):
    try:
        # Some code here
    except:
        # some code here
    finally:
        spark_session.stop()
```

According to the official documentation, `spark_session.stop()` stops the underlying `sparkcontext` in the `sparksession`.

My issue is that is it the correct method? If not, what is the way to just stop the `sparksession`?

Comment: `spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()` being done, I never stop the session. It will stop itself at the end of the program, and until then, will serve for all the requests.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response @MarcLeBihan Can you also tell in what situations should there be a need to use `spark_session.stop()` ?

Comment: Myself, I've found none. Usually, if you start Spark, if for application life. It comsumes resources when used, else not.